# Sort descending of a class vector

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a class that defined as

```
class chromosome
{
   vector<vector <int> > P(3,vector <int> (5,0));
   vector<int> F;       
}
```

I want to sort F in descending order, and the P corresponding with F will be sorted. For example,
   **Before sort**

```
    P    F
    101  4
    111  8
    001  2
    110  5
    100  3
```

**After sort**

```
    P    F
    111  8
    110  5
    101  4
    100  3
    001  2
```

How to implelement it by C++. I tried to used sort function in vector class. However, it only sort F. The P order is not change
This is my code

```
std::sort(F.rbegin(),F.rend());
```

Comment: Please post some realistic code.

Comment: @juanchopanza: check my work that I tried

Comment: Please post some realistic code. That is valid C++.

Comment: @user8264 I think juanchopanza is suggesting you [read this.](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is by sorting them after associating the order of `P` with the order of `F`, i.e. the first element in `P` sticks with the first element in `F` and so on. To do this you can use the `make_pair` command.

```
vector< pair<int, vector<int> > > X;
for (int i = 0; i < F.size(); i++)
  X.push_back(make_pair(F[i], P[i]));
```

This will create a vector consisting of pairs of elements of `F` and `P`. After this, you need to sort the array. Calling the simple sort function is defined for pairs in the manner that the first elements are compared first, followed by the second one. So, to sort the vector `X`, the command would be

```
sort(X.begin(), X.end())
```

After this, you need to put back the values from the sorted vector `X` into `F` and `P`. To do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < F.size(); i++)
{
  F[i] = X[i].first;
  P[i] = X[i].second;
}
```

Comment: That would be for `sort`ing a `vector<chromosome>`. He is talking about sorting the two internal `vector`s in synch with each other.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make a lot of sense. Think about how your instructions could be turned into code solving the problem. (i.e. as far as I can make out, they can't.)

Comment: @BobTFish: I have posted a comprehensive answer. Feedback would be welcome.

Comment: It had error sir. error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: @user8264 That's because he tries to access `vector` elements using `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Yes. I got it. But it still has error error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc>::push_back(int &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'int &&' and error C2228: left of '.first' must have class/struct/union

Comment: @user8264: This error was due to a mistake on my part. In the code example given above, I had forgotten to mention `pair` while defining X. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Comment: Thank for your solution. I have more knowledge about vector class

Comment: @BoBTFish: Thanks for pointing out the mistake again. I have been working a lot with MATLAB recently, and so my syntax is messed up.

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to sort by key using STL. Sorting with `std::sort` require single iterator for `begin` and `end`, so you have to write some wrapper that will handle both vectors as single iterator.

In general:

- moving iterator (`operator++` and `operator--`) should move 2 underlying iterators,
- comparison should compare only by the keys
- you have to handle element swapping in 2 underlying iterators

Take a look at [Sorting two arrays simultaneously](http://web.stanford.edu/~dgleich/notebook/2006/03/sorting_two_arrays_simultaneou.html). It's detailed description how to solve your problem.

Alternatively, maybe you can consider using `map< int, vector<int> >` instead of two vectors?

Comment: [Please don't just post link-only answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/242291) In its current form, your answer should just be a comment. Please add some explanation of the technique to your answer. (The link could still be a useful addition to your answer though).